# How to define an editable TableCell in FXML?

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml

I followed [this Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm) to create a TableView in FXML. However there is no info on how to make a cell editable. I have tried other tutorials suggesting to add something like `firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit( new EventHandler ...` into the controller code, but it didn't work. No matter how I click the mouse or punch the keyboard, the table cell does not change into the "editable textbox", as seen in here:

[image]

Here is my FXML definition of the table:

```
<TableView fx:id="tvAlgorithmSteps" editable="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn editable="true" prefWidth="150.0" sortable="false" text="Step">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="stepName" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        ...
```

The autocomplete allows me to set `onEditCommit=""` on the TableColumn in the FXML, but I have no idea what to put in there.

How should I edit the FXML to allow edits on the cells?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a [`cellFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellFactoryProperty) creating editable cells, e.g. [`TextFieldTableCell`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html). If the `PropertyValueFactory` returns a writable property, `onEditCommit` shouldn't be necessary

```xml
<TableColumn editable="true" prefWidth="150.0" sortable="false" text="Step">
    <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="stepName" />
    </cellValueFactory>
    <cellFactory>
        <TextFieldTableCell fx:factory="forTableColumn" />
    </cellFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

You may need to add a processing instruction to import the `TextFieldTableCell` class to the beginning of the file (but after `<?xml ...`):

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell?>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be enough to change values in model objects (through SimpleStringProperties)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Leprechaun as long as there is a property getter returning the property (e.g. `StringProperty stepNameProperty()`), it should work, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/2229/tableview/7289/propertyvaluefactory#t=201608121148083945414

Comment: I am having issues with this implementation not binding to stepName when you make a change. it has no issues retrieving the value though.